# How to update the XML node value and remove the XML node based on the node name in Azure Logic App

Tags: xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have logic app to process the XML. I want to update XML node value with new value and delete the XML node based on the node name.

So, can anyone suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed a logic app workflow for you, you can [convert your xml to json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#json), and then process it in [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code):

[image]

Finally, you can [convert execution result of inline code to xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xml):

[image]

I tested it and the result seems to be no problem:

[image]

**Original xml file**

```
<TransmissionDetail>
    <Sender>testSendeer</Sender>
    <Receiver>testReceiver</Receiver>
    <Subject>testSubject</Subject>
    <CommCreated>2020-06-23 22:38:27</CommCreated>
</TransmissionDetail>
```

**Results after updating and deleting nodes**

```
<TransmissionDetail>
    <Sender>newSender</Sender>
    <Receiver>testReceiver</Receiver>
    <Subject>testSubject</Subject>
</TransmissionDetail>
```

**Note**

Inline code need a [integration account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account).

Comment: Whenever I am trying to convert JavaScript output to XML then it contains `<body>` xml tag. please suggest how to remove this tag?

Comment: Could you please check the execution result to see at which step the `body` appears? Does the returned `JavaScript output` contain body?

Comment: Got it, I think we need to use this expression `xml(outputs('Execute_JavaScript_Code')?['body'])`